# Move BI Center (Excel, PerformancePoint, PowerPivot) to other SQL server - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, excel-services, performancepoint, powerpivot

What way would be the best to move BI Center to other SQL server in SharePoint 2013? Thanks,

Comment: I think that this is a good place to start. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729805(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yes but in my case I have to migration only BI Center Site Collection to other SQL, content of Farm, Web Application and so on stay in current server?

Comment: Ah, i understand. Well moving a site collection ain't hard, but you will need to have the service applications associated with the new webapplicaion, and configure the excel service account to have permission to the new content database.. I'm sure that is more that you need to do. Do you have a testing environment?

Comment: your BI site collection is own content DB or it is shared the database with other Site collections? is BI site collection in own Web Application?

Comment: Yes, We have testing farm amd BI Center is on own Web Application. It started when BI Center was on SharePoint 2010, in test farm We migrated it to SharePoint 2013 but in the same SQL server. Next We migrated SQL from 2008 R2 to SQL 2014 with all Analysis databeses and now We will have to migrate BI Center from test to production and I'm wondering which connection I have to change - only in Excel Services? We have quite lots of Dashboards also?

Comment: SO you want to move it from Test to Production?

Answer (score 0):

To move the BI Center Site collection,

- Make Sure All services Application are created and associated to the web application which you want to move the BI Site
- Now backup the Content DB of the BI Site collection.
- Restore into the Production SQL Server.
- Mount the DB to desired web Application.

Comment: Yes but to which SQL Server? In my case SharePoint Farm has own SQL Server and the Farm is working correct. Now I have to move BI Solutions from test Farm to production but the case is that BI databases are in other SQL Server and it will in other SQL Server. I'm wondering where I have to change connections in BI? In production I have all service application created, So I move content of Web Application and Site Collection and database of BI to SQL where is Farm SQL but how to connect BI Center (Excel, PerformancePoint etc) to new other SQL Server?